# How is a void pointer dereferenced back to the original struct in C?

Tags: c, xcode4, void-pointers

I am having trouble giving a struct value to a C interface for a queue that manages the queue as a linked list. It holds onto the data as void pointers to allow the interface to manage any data generically. I pass in the value as a pointer reference which is then saved as a void pointer. Later when it is returned I do not know how to cast the void pointer back to the original value.

What do I need to do? Here is the sample struct.

```
typedef struct MyData {
    int mNumber;
} MyData;
```

To simplify everything I have created a dummy function that simulates everything in a few lines of code.

```
void * give_and_go(void *data) {
    void *tmp = data;
    return tmp;
}
```

You can see it takes in a void pointer, sets it as a local variable and then returns it. Now I need to get the original value back.

```
MyData inVal;
inVal.mNumber = 100;
void * ptr = give_and_go(&inVal);
MyData outVal; // What converts ptr to the out value?
```

This is where I am stuck. I am using Xcode and it will not allow me to simply cast ptr to MyData or various alternatives that I have tried.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have found that I can use MyData outVal1 = *(MyData *)ptr; as well as MyData *outVal2 = (MyData *)ptr; to get back to the original value to access the struct value. Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Casting back to (MyData *) is indeed the way to do it.

Comment: Note that if you take a `void*` as a data member or function parameter, without any accompanying parameters/members, you are saying you don't care what is in it. But if you cast it later down the line, you have to care. So you're either going to either have to pass around `MyData*` directly (and skip the `void*` idea), or provide a way to let your code know that it will need to convert to a `MyData*`, e.g. pass around an `enum` saying what your type is, along with the `void*`.  Having your code make assumptions about what is in it will cause tricky bugs down the line, so give it some thought..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your void* back to a MyData*, then dereference it.

`MyData *outVal = (MyData*)(ptr);`

Answer (score 4):

You should assign the void-pointer to a MyData-pointer:

```
MyData *outVal = ptr;
```

If you are using C++, you will have to explicitly cast it, which I recommend anyway, since it works in both languages:

```
MyData *outVal = (MyData *)ptr;
```

In either case, you can then deference using the `->` operator:

```
outVal->mNumber
```

You can also assign the struct itself thus:

```
MyData outVal = *(MyData *)ptr;
```

But this copies the struct, whereas the other forms leave you pointing back to the original struct (i.e., assigning to `outVal->mNumber` will change `inVal.mNumber`, and vice-versa). There is no *a priori* preference one way or other. It just depends on what you intend.

Comment: I did not realize the second option would copy the struct. I want to be very efficient with memory here so I will go with the first suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: As long as you're aware that when you need a copy, you need a copy.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell about the code you provided, you are trying to cast a void pointer back to a non-pointer type.  This won't work.

Instead, cast your void pointer back to a *pointer* of the correct type:

```
MyData inVal;
inVal.mNumber = 100;
void* ptr = give_and_go(& inVal);
MyData* outVal = (MyData*)ptr;
```

Comment: I've learned that I really should malloc the struct first so my original example is bad. I should installed do MyData *inVal = (MyData *)malloc(sizeof(MyData)); and then I can pass it around and cast it directly like I did the call to malloc here.